# Gather digits from dial-pad while in room

Tags: twilio, twilio-programmable-voice

We're using Programmable Voice to allow users to dial-into our Programmable Video rooms. Is it possible to respond to dial-pad input after the phone user has been connected to a room? One use case we have is to allow a user to unmute themselves.

Answer (score 1):

You could investigate the approach using [hangupOnStar](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/dial#hanguponstar). That is the only way I am aware of today.

[Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41174934/twilio-conference-get-dialedin-participants-phone-input)